# Is docker using only one host OS?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I have been reading and fiddling around with docker, but I don't understand the layered architecture for `docker` and `docker for windows`.

**1** I do not understand for standard docker when you have the basic linux on which the docker daemon is installed, and you come with an application that requires `Linux A`.

Is docker basically doing the following:

1. Do `Linux A` - `Basic Linux` and get all the required delta dependencies
2. Run the application as a process directly on the `Basic OS` + the dependencies installed

   or

   Do `Linux A`-`Basic Linux` get delta **AND** run a new OS instance for our application..in which case shouldn't it be using a VM?or else how can you run an OS inside another OS without a VM? ( i am  newbie )

Could someone shed some light?

**2** As for docker for windows i understand that on top of what you have for docker for linux , you have your windows, you launch a VM and from there you repeat what i wrote earlier (starting from a `Base Linux`)

Comment: "Do Linux A - Basic Linux and get all the required delta dependencies" - No, none of that. No "delta dependency calculation". Docker images bundle all the dependencies they need.

Comment: "run as a process directly on the Basic OS" - also no. Process is isolated in a  container. You can think ot it as a super-lightweight VM.

Comment: *"How can you run an OS inside another OS without a VM?"* - A good place to start would be understanding what a chroot jail is. The LXC infrastructure used by Docker is basically that, but moreso (with different namespaces not just for the filesystem, but also the process tree, network configuration, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one OS(kernal). If it is Linux docker then one Linux Kernal(base OS) per docker. You can add a layer of .net runtime on top it, then an application on top it. 
[image]